# How to convert column type of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe where most columns are of type "object". I want to sort some like int, date or float.

I'm trying this through a dict:

```
df = df.astype(
    {
        'ID': int,
        'Data': date,
        'ID_Moto': int,
        'ID_Veiculo': int,
        'Pacotes_e': int,
        'Data_de_coleta ': date,
        'Pacotes_c': int
    }
)
```

But it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

what should I do?

Comment: int cannot have None ... there is no NaN for `int` datatype  ... you could use float instead i assume

Comment: It seems one of the columns of your dataframe is a string or nan and not a number. Provide a sample of your dataframe to have a look.

Comment: @Joran there is if you use 'Int64' dtype, use `convert_dtypes()` or `astype('Int64')`

Comment: @mozway imho that leads to more problem than it solves usually ... but yeah

Comment: @Joran why? Having floats in a column in which it would rather make sense to have integers is also problematic.

Comment: mostly around data transfer ... since int64 is less serializeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Int64 dtype:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2, None]})

df = df.astype({'col': 'Int64'})
```

Or for automatic conversion if possible, [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html):

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

Output:

```
    col
0     1
1     2
2  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use fillna() which turns all none values to a value of your choosing. Like this:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

This will convert all your 'NoneType' values to 0's and your code won't encounter any issues with those cells